# If parent has child menu then click twice to go to link, if no child menu click once to link through

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a mobile menu that has slide functionality.

By default, only the parent pages show. If a parent has a child then when a user clicks it I want to slide down the sub menu and if they click again then I want it to link through to the parent page and if the parent page hasn't got a child then I want it to link through straight away.

This is the code I've got but I know there's a bug or four in there. Hopefully someone can help out :)

```
if($(".mob-navigation > ul > li > a").next(".sub-menu").length) {
  $(this).one("click", true);
} else {
  $(this).one("click", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your HTML looks like so it's a bit hard to write the exact code for you. But maybe you can check if the sub-menu is visible? If it is visible then go to the parent page, if else you can make the sub-menu visible.

Answer (score 1):

```js
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $("#subnav").parent("li").addClass("hassub");
                $("#subnav").parent("li").append("<div class='overlay'></div>");
                $(".hassub").click(function (){
                    $("#subnav").toggle();
                    $(".overlay").toggle();
                });
            });
```

```css
ul{
                list-style: none;
                width: 150px;
            }
            li{
                padding: 5px 10px;
                height: 15px;
                background: #cccccc;
                margin: 1px 0;
            }
            li.hassub{
                height: auto;
                position: relative;
                background: #bbbbbb;
            }
            a{
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            #nav{
                
            }
            #subnav{
                display: none;
                
            }
            .overlay{
                height: 25px;
                content: " ";
                width: 100%;
                background: rgba(255,0,0,.3);
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 1;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://softdesigns.in/">About</a>
                <ul id="subnav">
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.co.in">Personal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Professional</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Try this one. I hope this is you are looking for.